# OptaPlanner + Drools - how to create specific rule

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm working on a kind of "employee rostering" application. I'm using OptaPlanner and its ability to work with Drools.

I have three classes: `Employee`, `Shift`, `ShiftAssignment`.

`Shift` class has a property called length which basically means how many hours the `Shift` lasts.

As you can figure out, `ShiftAssignment` is the `@PlanningEntity` class that has properties of `Employee` and `Shift` types. Moreover the `ShiftAssignment` class has a method that returns its `Shift` lenght.

`Employee` is the `@PlanningVariable`.

I would like to have a rule that checks if every single `Employee` has worked for at least 160  hours in total. The problem is I have no idea how to implement such a rule in drools. Can someone please help me with this and provide me such a rule? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Might want to take a look at: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/solver/nurseRosteringScoreRules.drl

Comment: yea, see the total assignements rule and replace count(assignment) by sum(assignment.getHours()).